# Finding number of copy engines using OpenCL

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

In OpenCL is there any API for finding number of copy engines in GPU? In cuda we can check this with `asyncEngineCount.` What is the alternative in OpenCL?

Answer (score 2):

Within the OpenCL standard, there is no alternative because this is a hardware- and vendor-specific implementation detail. However, in the future, NVIDIA might update its `cl_nv_device_attribute_query` extension. This extension already contains the [`CL_DEVICE_GPU_OVERLAP_NV`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.2/cl_ext.h) device info, that returns true if asynchronous copy is possible.